# How to Convert a For Each x In {a,b,c } From VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, loops, for-loop

I am really not familiar with VB, but generally can manage to convert code from VB into C#. This time, I am really not sure how to do.

Here is the existing code:

```
For Each ctl In {gbGrbl, gbJogging, gbGcode}
     ctl.Location = New Point(3, ctl.Location.Y)
Next
```

"*gbGrbl, gbJogging, gbGcode*" are Windows form fields in a groupbox.

What would be the best way to translate this into C#?

Thanks for your help,
Bernard.

Comment: `in new Control[] { ... }`

Comment: @Visual Vincent. If I ask here, it is because none of the online converters I tried, including Telerik, are able to make a correct translation for this.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'll look into this, did not think at it this way.

Comment: @VisualVincent: Sure, but Telerik fails for this example.

Comment: @BernardG : Well if you don't show your attempts or don't say anything like _"I struggle to convert this part: ..."_, people (like I) _**might**_ interpret your question as that you haven't tried anything and just want it converted. :)

Comment: @Visual Vincent: I see your point, but generally I post here only after I tried everything I could. Maybe I need to make this more obvious, so I welcome your suggestion.

Comment: @BernardG : Well it was just a misunderstanding :). Good luck with the coding in the future!

Answer (score 2):

I'm only posting the C# equivalent here because the online converters fail for this example, so in light of that I think this is a reasonable question:

```
foreach (var ctl in new[] {gbGrbl, gbJogging, gbGcode})
{
     ctl.Location = new Point(3, ctl.Location.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ivan hint was the correct answer:

```
foreach (Control ctl in new Control[] { gbGrbl, gbJogging, gbGcode})
{
    ctl.Location = new Point(3, ctl.Location.Y);
}
```

Comment: True, but sometimes it is helpful to see the explicitly typed version. Though the extra loop variable was a bit much. (Perhaps that was from an auto-converter?)